# how can i change the sql get the union result

Tags: sql-server

how can i change the select...

Student
id name  home  tel
1  A     Neo   023** 
2  A     Cit   012**
3  B     Dti   12**
4  ..    ...   ...

I have a select sql query like:

```
SELECT
    name,
    home,
    tel
FROM Student
WHERE id<4;
```

And the result was like↓
name home tel
A    Neo  023** 
 
A    Cit  012**
B    Dti  12**

But I want to get the result like
name home    tel
A    Neo,Cit 023**,012**
B    Dti     12**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CURSOR or a CTE and concatenate the strings in the home and tel fields. See [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21082/Concatenate-Field-Values-in-One-String-Using-CTE-i) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @Student table (id int, name varchar(10), home varchar(100), tel varchar(10))
insert into @Student select 1, 'A', 'Neo', '023**' 
insert into @Student select 2, 'A', 'Cit', '012**'
insert into @Student select 3, 'B', 'Dti', '12**'

select * from @Student

select name, stuff((
        select distinct ',' + u.home
        from @Student u
        where u.name = s.name
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') as home, stuff((
        select distinct ',' + u.tel
        from @Student u
        where u.name = s.name
        for xml path('')),1,1,'') as tel
from @Student s
group by name
```